# Flutter Firestore asynchronous Functions/ Wait for result

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

Im trying to get all the posts from a group that a user is a member of from firebase. My problem now is that the program is not waiting until the list groupsPosts has data and continues executing code.

```
getTimelineWithGroupPosts() async {
   List groupIDs = [];
   List<QuerySnapshot> groupsPosts = [];
   List allPosts = [];

   QuerySnapshot snapshot = await usersGroupsRef
       .document(currentUser.id)
       .collection("usersGroups")
       .getDocuments();

   snapshot.documents.forEach((element) {
     groupIDs.add(element.documentID.toString());
   });
   print(groupIDs);

     groupIDs.forEach((data) async {
       groupsPosts.add(await groupPostsRef
           .document(data)
           .collection("groupPosts")
           .getDocuments());
       print(groupsPosts);
     });


   print(groupsPosts);

   groupsPosts.forEach((data) {
     allPosts.add(data.documents);
   });
   print(allPosts);

   List<Post> posts = allPosts.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();

   setState(() {
     groupPosts = posts;
   });
 }
```

```
I/flutter (11768): [1de5aec6-612e-41e8-90b2-04781b2a2954, 3545784b-0fca-4d35-bd0d-5d877e58808f, 66036190-304f-4984-9e7a-1a9a92e83466]
I/flutter (11768): []
I/flutter (11768): []
I/flutter (11768): [Instance of 'QuerySnapshot']
I/flutter (11768): [Instance of 'QuerySnapshot', Instance of 'QuerySnapshot']
I/flutter (11768): [Instance of 'QuerySnapshot', Instance of 'QuerySnapshot', Instance of 'QuerySnapshot']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) does not await returned futures. Instead, use [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-async/Future/wait.html):

```dart
groupPosts.addAll(
  await Future.wait(
    groupIDs.map(
      (data) => groupPostsRef
          .document(data)
          .collection("groupPosts")
          .getDocuments(),
    ),
  ),
);
```